# Naive-Matcher worst case running time

Tags: algorithm

Given the following pseudocode:

```
Naive-Matcher(T , P )
1. n <- T.length
2. m <- P.length
3. create a new empty queue S
4. for s <- 0 to n <- m do
  5. matches <- TRUE
  6. for i <- 1 to m do
    7. if P[i] /= T[s + i] then
      8. matches <- FALSE
      9. exit for loop
 10. if matches then enqueue(s, S)
```

Let T (n, m) denote the worst case runtime of the algorithm Naive-Matcher on inputs of size n and m respectively. How can I prove that T (n, m) = Ω((n * m + 1)m)

Comment: Is it `Ω((n * m + 1)m)` or `Ω((n + m + 1)m)`?

Comment: n*m, sorry I wrote it wrong

Comment: What does `for s <- 0 to n <- m do` mean?